# android studio generate apk with different fingerprint from apk generated with eclipse and same certificate

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, code-signing

I have a legacy android project that was made with eclipse and recently I updated that project to use android studio. When I try to submit the signed apk, google play says that it was signed with a different certificate than the previous one. But I'm SURE that is the same certificate. If I generate an apk with eclipse it works, but in android studio, even using the same certificate, it doesn't.

If I print the certificate in the apk generated with eclipse, I get:

```
Owner: CN=Luciano...
Issuer: CN=Luciano...
Serial number: 35623238373966383a31333432326637373064303a2d38303030
Valid from: Thu Dec 08 11:16:08 BRST 2011 until: Tue Dec 09 11:16:08 BRST 2036
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  9A:CB:***:AA:88
     SHA1: 0D:BA:***:20:9B
     SHA256: CA:3F:***:90:58
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  codeSigning
]
```

But if I print the certificate in the apk generated with android studio, I get:

```
Owner: CN=Luciano...
Issuer: CN=Luciano...
Serial number: 35623238373966383a31333432326637373064303a2d38303030
Valid from: Thu Dec 08 11:16:08 BRST 2011 until: Tue Dec 09 11:16:08 BRST 2036
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  E1:51:***:7A:08
     SHA1: 63:F0:***:65:CF
     SHA256: 66:57:***:B9:CB
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3

Extensions: 

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
ExtendedKeyUsages [
  codeSigning
]
```

The certificates have the same serial number, but different fingerprints.

I tried generating an unsigned apk with gradle and manually signing it, and it works. Better explained, if I sign the apk manually, google play accepts it. Is this an android studio bug?

I tested against Android Studio version 1.4.1, Build #AI-141.2343393, and Android Build Tools 23.0.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this to sign with-in android studio and get correct fingerprints?

Comment: No, I didn't. As I said in the question, I'm generating an unsigned apk with gradle and manually signing it. That's the only way I've found to get an correct apk.

Comment: I spent some more time on it to find out what's the difference. I think if the keystore uses digest algorithm 'SHA1withRSA', android studio generates signed apk which will have different fingerprints, because, I guess, Android Sudio is using SHA256withRSA by default.  I have extracted private key from my certificate and tried to recreate the keykstore by using SHA256. Then even keytool is outputting the fingerprints same as Android Studio.  I must say android studio should provide a mechanism to specify what algorithm it should use while singing the apk.